# How to retrieve all new created VIEWS for 2022 under a BigQuery Project

Tags: google-bigquery

So I am tasked with querying and finding all new VIEWS created in 2022 under a specific BQ project.
I know that there are specific queries to use to pull all TABLES and VIEWS under a project.

I TRIED using SELECT * FROM myProject.'region-us'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE creation_time LIKE '%2022%'

however this column only applies to TABLES, not VIEWS.  There seems to be no date/time column associated with VIEWS.  Is there another angle to approach this?

Comment: What about querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and adding table_type = "VIEW" as described here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

This seems to give you the data for views created

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use TABLES schema to get what you need:
[References: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views]

```
 SELECT * FROM `{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}.{YOUR_DATASET_NAME}`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 where table_type = 'VIEW' and DATE(creation_time) between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
```

If you want to get more details on that view, you can get more info from adding VIEWS into the mix joined on same ids.

Comment: Glad to know it helped! in that case, if u could accept this as ur correct answer to ur question that would be great, haha :D , thanks